# Two Problems in understanding the algorithm for computing shortest paths in undirected graphs with possibly negative edge weights

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, correctness-proof, matching

Section 2 of this [Lecture Note: Shortest Path Algorithms Luis Goddyn, Math 408](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~goddyn/Courses/800/Resources/GraphMisc/short_path.pdf) describes an algorithm using Edmonds' Minimum Weight Perfect Matching Algorithm to solve the shortest path problem for undirected graphs with negative-weight edges but no negative cycles.

I have two problems in understanding this algorithm:

- In step 3, why must $G'$ have perfect matchings so that we can apply Edmonds' Minimum Weight Perfect Matching Algorithm to $G'$?
- In step 4, why must each circuit in $S$ have total weight $0$?
  (A possible argument is like this: Because there are no negative cycles, we only need to show that each circuit in $S$ cannot have positive total weight. Maybe this can be proved by contradiction. Suppose that some circuit in $S$ have positive total weight, we need to show that $M$ is not a mimimum weight perfect matching or this cannot be a circuit. However, I failed to reach a contradiction.)

---

Related post: [Finding shortest paths in undirected graphs with possibly negative edge weights](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76578/4911).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the second problem is nice.

Here is an hint or strategy for the first problem.

Select a path $P$ from $s$ to $t$. Verify that there is perfect matching for the corresponding $P'$. Form graph $Q$ from $P$ by adding one vertex $u$ of $G$ not in $P$ (if there is) and all edges from $u$ to vertices in $P$. $P'$ is extended to $Q'$ correspondingly. A bit of reasoning by cases will show the previous perfect matching of $P'$ can be extended to a perfect matching of $Q'$. Now you can add another vertex, repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the second problem:

**Problem:** Each circuit in $S$ must have total weight zero. Why?

**Proof:** By contradiction.
Suppose that some circuit $C$ in $S$ have nonzero total weight.
Because $G$ has no negative cycles, $C$ has positive total weight.
Note that $C$ does not contain $s$ or $t$. Therefore, the edges of $C$ are all $5$-edge gadgets; see step 2.
Then we can construct another perfert matching on $C$ whose total weight is zero by choosing the middle edge with weight $0$ of each $5$-edge gadgets and the edges between $v$ and $v'$ (for each $v$ in $C$; see step 1) also with weight $0$.
This contradicts the assumption that $M$ is a minimum perfect matching.